# sharing authentication across multiple plugins in Grails

Tags: security, spring, authentication, plugins, grails

I have modularized a large Grails project into several plugins and want to share access to the spring security plugin to manage authentication across my project - is there an easy way to do this?  I'm not sure how to share access to core project plugins from sub plugins

Comment: I would like to know too. You might be interested in this. An item from the grails roadmap for 2.0 "Generic Security Abstraction Supported And Implemented By Different Plugins" http://www.grails.org/Roadmap

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring security grails plugin for your authentication, then just define this plugin in your base-sub-plugin,  like this:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    [..]
    plugins {
        compile ":spring-security-core:1.1.3"
        compile ":spring-security-ui:0.1.2"     
    }
}
```

All your your custom plugins, that use this plugin, will automatically get the security plugin as a dependency and can use the `springSecurityService` (and do not need to define these plugins in there application.properties).